# A problem about diagonalize invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a non-zero finite-dimensional vector space, **A** belongs to End($V$).
Also, for any invariant subspace $M$ of **A**, there exists an invariant subspace $N$ of **A** such that $V=M\oplus N$.

Prove: **A** is diagonalizable

Comment: What do you know about the underlying field over which $V$ is a vector space?

Comment: Thank you.I have to say that V is a  complex vector space

Comment: Hint: When $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, every $A \in \mathrm{End}(V)$ has an eigenvector, which spans a one-dimensional invariant subspace of $A$.

Comment: But that works only if A is a two dimensinal complex vetor space. Maybe I should use Mathematical Induction?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you can use the Jordan canonical form of $A$, we have the following proof by contradiction*:

Suppose not.  Then there is some eigenvalue $\lambda$ and some generalized eigenvector $v$ such that $$(A-\lambda I)v \neq 0 \\ (A-\lambda I)^2v = 0.$$
In other words, $A (A-\lambda I)v = \lambda (A-\lambda I)v$ so that $\mathbb{C}\cdot (A-\lambda I)v$ is an $A$-invariant subspace.

By assumption, there is some $A$-invariant subspace $N$ such that $V = \left(\mathbb{C}\cdot (A-\lambda I)v\right) \oplus N$, so in particular, $v = c(A-\lambda I)v + n$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\in N$.  Apply $A-\lambda I$ to both sides to show $$(A-\lambda I)v = c(A-\lambda I)^2v + (A-\lambda I)n = 0 + An - \lambda n \in N;$$
however, this shows $$(A-\lambda I)v \in (\mathbb{C}\cdot (A-\lambda I)v) \cap N = \{0\},$$
so $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$, a contradiction.